# Dynamic Symbol Table for PE compiled on Linux

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw-w64, portable-executable, symbol-table

I'm trying to get the content of the dynamic symbol table of compiled c file

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

as portable executable (PE) on Linux with

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc hello_world.c -o hello32
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc hello_world.c -o hello64
```

I'm using objdump:

```
objdump --dynamic-syms hello32
```

and get the output:

```
hello32:    file format pei-i386

objdump: hello32: not a dynamic object
DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

I would expect to have functions like printf in the table. It works with gcc and ELF binaries.

Does anyone know how to compile the file correctly to have a dynamic symbol table with content?

Comment: Aren't dynamic symbols supposed to be the symbols exported by your code?
In your example printf will be imported from the standard library.
An exported symbol in a shared library on Windows (.DLL file) is usually defined with __declspec(dllexport) in the code, but there are other ways (like listing exported symbols in a .def file and specifying that at link time).

Comment: @BrechtSanders As far as I have understood, the dynamic symbols are used by the linker to map functions from external libraries into the address space of the program that is currently being loaded. (e.g. printf). If I compile the same program as ELF binary, I get printf in the dynamic symbol table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of *dynamic symbols* seems to be a bit lost in PE-targetting binutils.  Use `objdump -p <file>` or `objdump -x <file>` and look for *import tables* in the output.  I haven't found a better solution with binutils yet.  There's `llvm-readobj --coff-imports <file>` from LLVM.  If you want to see where the symbols will come from at runtime, ntldd is a good tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will, however, now try to build some symbol analyzer to also check for stripped binaries. It's pity that objdump can't handle both PE and ELF.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dumpbin /imports hello32
```

and printf will be in the output table.